# python: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list" when open file

Tags: python

I try to read my input file.

```
Myfile = list(input("Please enter a filename with full dir: "))
fp = open(Myfile)
sstr = fp.read()
```

but always show the error:

```
"D:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" D:/Onebox/Python/my_help_doc/guo.py
Please enter a filename with full dir: 'E:\个人\郭周诺\Python\guo-python.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Onebox/Python/my_help_doc/guo.py", line 7, in <module>
    fp = open(Myfile)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Why do you convert the user input to a list? it makes no sense, just like the error explains

Comment: Why you put input in a `list`?

Answer (score 2):

you should have a path-like object not a list as param for the `open` built-in function

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> **open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None,
>   newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)**
>
> Open file and return a
>   corresponding file object. If the file cannot be opened, an OSError is
>   raised.
>
> `file is a path-like object` giving the pathname (absolute or relative
>   to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an
>   integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped. (If a file
>   descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is
>   closed, unless closefd is set to False.)

---

you may use a string as a param for the `open` function:

```
my_file = input("Please enter a filename with full dir: ")
fp = open(my_file)
```